# plot effects on glmer

Tags: data-visualization, glmm, lme4-nlme

I done a GLMM with the function `glmer` from `lme4`, the variable paternity is binomial (yes or no)(`model <- glmer(paternity~factor1, factor 2  ..., family=binomial`).

My model run correctly, but after I want plot the effect.
So I used the package effects.
When I plot my effect, the Y-axis is numeric but I do not understand what it mean because this axis is binomial (paternity yes or no) ...

How I must interpreted this ?

Comment: The results are probably on the log-odds scale. (They might be on a continuous probability scale.)

Comment: yes, but how I interpret this ? Does it mean that the probability of paternity rise with the log scale ? Or that the probability of losing paternity rise with the log scale ?

Comment: Please, show us the graph you are talking about and the  code to reproduce it. Tks.

Comment: Perhaps https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133623 now answers your question?