# From exp (coefficients) to Odds Ratio and their interpretation in Logistic Regression with factors

Tags: r, regression, logistic

I ran a linear regression of acceptance into college against SAT scores and family / ethnic background. The data are fictional. This is a follow-up on a prior question, already answered. The question focuses in the gathering and interpretation of odds ratios when leaving the SAT scores aside for simplicity.

The variables are `Accepted` (0 or 1) and `Background` ("red" or "blue"). I set up the data so that people of "red" background were more likely to get in:

```
fit <- glm(Accepted~Background, data=dat, family="binomial")
exp(cbind(Odds_Ratio_RedvBlue=coef(fit), confint(fit)))

                        Odds_Ratio_RedvBlue             2.5 %       97.5 %
(Intercept)             0.7088608                     0.5553459   0.9017961
Backgroundred           2.4480042                     1.7397640   3.4595454
```

Questions:

1. Is 0.7 the odd ratio of a person of "blue" background being accepted? I'm asking this because I also get 0.7 for "`Backgroundblue`" if instead I run the following code:

   ```
   fit <- glm(Accepted~Background-1, data=dat, family="binomial")
   exp(cbind(OR=coef(fit), confint(fit)))
   ```
2. Shouldn't the odds ratio of "red" being accepted ($\rm Accepted/Red:Accepted/Blue$) just the reciprocal: ($\rm OddsBlue = 1 / OddsRed$)?

Comment: What `R` explicitly calls the *coefficients* (via the function `coef`) you are calling the "odds ratio" in your output. That suggests you might want to review [the distinction between the two.](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133623)

Comment: I did read the post on your hyperlink.

Comment: The coefficients are exponentiated: exp(coef(fit)).

Comment: Yes: and as explained in my answer in that thread, exponentiation of the intercept gives you the *odds* of the reference case.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I've been working on answering my question by calculating manually the odds and odds ratios:

```
Acceptance   blue            red            Grand Total
0            158             102                260
1            112             177                289
Total        270             279                549
```

So the *Odds Ratio* of getting into the school of Red over Blue is:

$$
\frac{\rm Odds\ Accept\ If\ Red}{\rm Odds\ Acccept\ If\ Blue} = \frac{^{177}/_{102}}{^{112}/_{158}} = \frac {1.7353}{0.7089} = 2.448
$$

And this is the `Backgroundred`return of:

```
fit <- glm(Accepted~Background, data=dat, family="binomial")
exp(cbind(Odds_and_OR=coef(fit), confint(fit)))

                      Odds_and_OR                         2.5 %      97.5 %
(Intercept)             0.7088608                     0.5553459   0.9017961
Backgroundred           2.4480042                     1.7397640   3.4595454
```

At the same time, the `(Intercept)`corresponds to the numerator of the *odds ratio*, which is exactly the *odds* of getting in being of 'blue' family background: $112/158 = 0.7089$.

If instead, I run:

```
fit2 <- glm(Accepted~Background-1, data=dat, family="binomial")
exp(cbind(Odds=coef(fit2), confint(fit2)))

                        Odds            2.5 %      97.5 %
Backgroundblue     0.7088608        0.5553459   0.9017961
Backgroundred      1.7352941        1.3632702   2.2206569
```

The returns are precisely the *odds* of getting in being 'blue': `Backgroundblue` (0.7089) and the *odds* of being accepted being 'red':  `Backgroundred` (1.7353). No *Odds Ratio* there. Therefore the two return values are not expected to be reciprocal.

Finally, How to read the results if there are 3 factors in the categorical regressor?

Same manual versus [R] calculation:

I created a different fictitious data set with the same premise, but this time there were three ethnic backgrounds: "red", "blue" and "orange", and ran the same sequence:

First, the contingency table:

```
Acceptance  blue    orange  red   Total
0             86        65  130     281
1             64        42  162     268
Total        150       107  292     549
```

And calculated the *Odds* of getting in for each ethnic group:

- Odds Accept If Red = 1.246154;
- Odds Accept If Blue = 0.744186;
- Odds Accept If Orange = 0.646154

As well as the different *Odds Ratios*:

- OR red v blue = 1.674519;
- OR red v orange = 1.928571;
- OR blue v red = 0.597186;
- OR blue v orange = 1.151717;
- OR orange v red = 0.518519; and
- OR orange v blue = 0.868269

And proceeded with the now routine logistic regression followed by exponentiation of coefficients:

```
fit <- glm(Accepted~Background, data=dat, family="binomial")
exp(cbind(ODDS=coef(fit), confint(fit)))

                      ODDS     2.5 %   97.5 %
(Intercept)      0.7441860 0.5367042 1.026588
Backgroundorange 0.8682692 0.5223358 1.437108
Backgroundred    1.6745192 1.1271430 2.497853
```

Yielding the *odds* of getting in for "blues" as the `(Intercept)`, and the *Odds Ratios* of Orange versus Blue in `Backgroundorange`, and the OR of Red v Blue in `Backgroundred` .

On the other hand, the regression without intercept predictably returned just the three independent *odds*:

```
fit2 <- glm(Accepted~Background-1, data=dat, family="binomial")
exp(cbind(ODDS=coef(fit2), confint(fit2)))

                      ODDS     2.5 %    97.5 %
Backgroundblue   0.7441860 0.5367042 1.0265875
Backgroundorange 0.6461538 0.4354366 0.9484999
Backgroundred    1.2461538 0.9900426 1.5715814
```

Comment: Congratulations, you did a nice job of figuring this out.