# Log of the odds in Logistic Regression

Tags: regression, logistic, odds

In simple logistic regression i noticed that many researcher neglect the constant part of the logistic regression equation.

Log(odds) = a + b Gender (say that 0 = Female and 1 = Male)
So the log of the odds of cancer when the case is male is b ... and odds of course is exp(b)

but shouldn't the log of the odds equals b + a? because log(odds) = a + b x 1 = a + b

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133623/ probably answers your questions.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you've misinterpreted what someone wrote and they meant that males have $b$ higher log-odds than females.

$$
\log(odds) = a+bx\\
\log(odds) = a+b\text{ (male)}\\
\log(odds) = a+0\text{ (female)}\\
$$

Then subtract to see that $\log(odds)$ for males is $b$ higher than $\log(odds)$ for females.

Comment: Yeah I understand it like what you said. But I in many articles it's just interpreted as: odds of cancer for males is exp(b), without taking care of a