# How to express the form of a Logistic Regression when a categorical predictor has more than 2 levels

Tags: regression, logistic, multiple-regression

Like let's say my predictor X has four levels, 1, 2, 3, and 4. Fitting a logistic regression will generate estimates of $\beta$ for x = 2, x = 3, and x = 4, and I understand that each of these estimates reflects the odds ratio of that level of x to the reference level of x = 1.

My question is, how do I express that model in a general form?

I don't think this is correct:

$\log\frac{\pi(x)}{1-\pi(x)}=\beta_0+\beta_1x + \beta_2x+\beta_3x$

...because this would imply that I could set different values for each x, which I cannot. I'm not allowed to do x=2 AND x=3, for example.

But then this ALSO seems incorrect:

$\log\frac{\pi(x)}{1-\pi(x)}=\beta_0+\beta x$

...because I have multiple slopes here, not just a single $\beta$.

So how do I actually write this formula?

Comment: How would you do it in a linear regression (e.g., ANOVA)?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133623.  Perhaps that answers your question?  If not, searching our site for "dummy variable coding" will turn up plenty of helpful material.

Comment: @Dave - that's the second formula, but that doesn't parallel to my situation because in my situation I generate multiple slopes, not just one.

Comment: What is your $x$ variable in the second formula when you do an ANOVA?

Comment: @Dave x = 1, 2, 3, or 4 in my example.

Comment: Why doesn't that work for logistic regression?

Comment: @Dave because each individual x has a unique $\beta$ in logistic regression.

Comment: Why doesn’t that happen in linear regression?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134432/discussion-between-dan-w-and-dave).

Answer (score 0):

Let's first work it out in the case of linear regression.

Let's take a predictor variable that has two levels, cat and dog, and that will be our only predictor.

$$
\mathbb E[y] = \beta_0x_{cat} + \beta_1x_{dog} 
$$

The $x_{animal}$ variables take the value $1$ if the subject is that animal and $0$ if the subject is not that animal.

However, it is more common to use an intercept and then a variable that compares one of the factors to the other.

$$
\mathbb E[y] = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_{dog} 
$$

Here, $x_{dog}$ takes the value $1$ if the subject is a dog and $0$ if the subject is not a dog. This just as easily could have been done for a cat, but the cats aren't missing from the model. The cats become a reference category with their mean given by the intercept $\beta_0$, and then $\beta_1$ is by how much the mean for dogs differs from the mean for cats.

For example, if we have cats with a mean mass of $4$ kg and dogs with a mass weight of $40$ kg, our regression equation would be $\mathbb E[y] = 4 + 36x_{dog}$.

Now let's also look at horses, which have a mean mass of $250$ kg. We expand our regression equation to have a variable $x_{horse}$ that takes $1$ if the subject is a horse and $0$ otherwise.

$$
\mathbb E[y] = 4 + 36x_{dog} + 246x_{horse}
$$

If we include alligators that have a mean mass of $225$ kg, then we get:

$$
\mathbb E[y] = 4 + 36x_{dog} + 246x_{horse} + 221x_{gator}
$$

If we didn't know the means for each animal and had to estimate them from the data, we might propose the following model and then estimate the coefficients using a method like ordinary least squares.

$$
\mathbb E[y] = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_{dog} + \beta_2x_{horse} + \beta_3x_{gator}
$$

But you didn't ask about linear models. You asked about generalized linear models that deal with $g(\mathbb E[y])$ instead of just $\mathbb E[y]$. For a binary response variable $y$ whose log-odds of occurance depends on the species (cat, dog, horse, or alligator), we might propose the following model, for $g(p)=\log\big(\frac{p}{1-p}\big)$, $p\in(0,1)$.

$$
g(\mathbb E[y]) = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_{dog} + \beta_2x_{horse} + \beta_3x_{gator}
$$

As usual, the $x_{animal}$ variables take $1$ if the subject is that animal and $0$ otherwise.