# How do I write logistic regression for a categorical predictor?

Tags: regression, logistic

I've read so many previous posts but still feel confused. I've run a logistic regression based on one categorical predictor with two levels. I know with continuous predictors, I can calculate the probability of an event $(Y)$ as $P(Y)=exp(b0+b1x)/1+exp(b0+b1x)$. However, I'm really confused on how to calculate $P(Y)$ for categorical predictors based on the output pasted below for dummy data. Does anyone know what equation to use?

```
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept)   2.4893     0.2721   3.874  0.00645 **
s21to60.L     0.5286     0.1638   2.921  0.00854 **
```

Comment: Would https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133623 answer your question?

Comment: Yes, thank you!