# Transforming the Odds ratio of logistic regression coefficients to the original scale

Tags: regression, logistic, mathematical-statistics, odds-ratio

I have fitted a logistic regression model with a transformed variable $z$, where $z=x/M$. I want to interpret the $\beta$ coefficients in the original scale (in-terms of x).

I started following calculation. First, I wrote the Odds rations in the transformed scale, as follows:

let $\pi_1=logit(p1)=\beta_0+\beta_1z$ and  $\pi_2=logit(p2)=\beta_0+\beta_1(z+1)$. Then, $\pi_1-\pi_2=log(\hat{OR})=\beta_1$. And $\hat{OR}=exp(\beta_1)$. This $OR$ was calculated based on z. Now, I want to calculate $OR$ for x.

My friends said that **$OR$ based on x would be $exp(\beta_1/M)$**. I want to prove it.

So I substitute $z=x/M$ in the above calculation. Then,

$\pi_1=logit(p1)=\beta_0+\beta_1x/M$ and  $\pi_2=logit(p2)=\beta_0+\beta_1(x/M+1)$

$\pi_1-\pi_2=log(\hat{OR})=\beta_1$. This is not what I expected. Correct answer should be $\beta_1/M$

Could anyone explain what did I do wrong?

Comment: quick question, why do you want to do this? to see the effect of an increase of 1 for x wrt the predicted probability?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia  Actually, the reason is the odds ratios in the transformed scale is very large. So, I need to convert it to the original scale. Could you help me?  I wanted to show the results like the table 5 in the paper: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0376871622002137

Comment: They used exp(beta\M). But my calculation don't give that.

Comment: I don't quite get your calculation, it's quite late where I am, however, I see that $\beta_1/M$ is the correct answer by  the simple fact that affine transformations of convex functions, does not change the minimum... in other words, if $\beta_1$ is optimum for $z$ and $z = x/M$ then $\beta1 / M$ will be the optimum for $x$... however, if you can wait tomorrow morning, I'll try to spot the issue in your reasoning

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia Yes. I can wait. Thank you very much.

Comment: You are not computing the ratios.  For a detailed explanation, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133623.